# How to omit lines when quoting a play

Tags: quotes, ellipses, omissibility

I am citing the play *All My Sons* in an essay I am writing.

I don't want to have a lot of unnecessary content in my quotes and I am not too familiar with quoting plays, so I want to ask how I should omit lines when quoting a play.

P.S. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, so it would be great if you could refer me to the best site for these kind of questions.

Comment: Are you using a style guide?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am using MLA format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MLA, you use a line of ellipses when you're omitting entire lines:

> When omitting words from poetry quotations, use a standard three-period ellipses; however, when omitting one or more full lines of poetry, space several periods to about the length of a complete line in the poem:
>
> > These beauteous forms,
> >     Through a long absence, have not been to me
> >     As is a landscape to a blind man's eye:
> >     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
> >     Felt in the blood, and felt along the heart;
> >     And passing even into my purer mind,
> >     With tranquil restoration . . . (22-24, 28-30)
>
> <sub>Purdue OWL: [MLA Formatting Quotations](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_quotations.html)</sub>